# Linechart with labelled plots

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex-charting

I have a line chart with 4 line series with diamond, circle, box and triangle as item renderer for the plots for these 4 line series. Now my requirement is I want to show labels for the plots in the chart. It should be like this :

[image]
<sub>(source: [infocaptor.com](http://www.infocaptor.com/user_help/dashboard_line_chart_image_0.png))</sub>

I tried with some item renderes but not getting it correctly since I want to use the circles and triangles to render the plots. This is killing my time. Please Help...

Cheers, PK

Answer (score 1):

The link to the example image in your question is broken at the moment, but if you are looking to add labels to your plot, you can use the `CartesianDataCanvas` class to position elements relative to data coordinates in your chart.  If that's what you are looking to do then the second example [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_eventsandeffects_13.html) should tell you everything you need to know.  Again, I can't see the picture of what you are trying to achieve, but it you want the labels on all of your plotted values than another option is to set `showAllDataTips` to true on your chart object and create a custom `dataTipRenderer` for the plot.  In that case [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_08.html) example should be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Use [localToContent](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/core/UIComponent.html#localToContent%28%29) and [dataToLocal](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/charts/chartClasses/IChartElement2.html#dataToLocal%28%29) on the dataProvider:

```
p1_label.text = line1.dataProvider[0].x;
p1_label.x = component.parent.localToContent
    (line1.dataToLocal
       (line1.dataProvider[0].x,line1.dataProvider[0].y)
    ).x - 10;
p1_label.y = component.parent.localToContent
    (line1.dataToLocal
      (line1.dataProvider[0].x,line1.dataProvider[0].y)
    ).y - 10;
```